# PHP code is running a functional query for one input but not for more inputs. Not showing any error, just an empty output. Why?

Tags: php

I made an SQL query and tested it, it works in mysql. The project is the following:

The user can input in a search box several different values (codes) separated by a comma, and then the output retrieves attribute data for each of the user's desired codes. For one inputted code, the output table shows the attributes. However when I add more codes, it shows an empty table. Any idea why this is happening?

The HTML input:

```
<form action="ausgabe_20.07.php" target="myiframe" method="POST" >
<p><input name="AGI1" type="text"> </p>
```

The PHP code:

```
if($_POST['AGI1']<>''){
    $sProt = $_POST['AGI1'];
  
    $sProt = strtoupper($sProt);
    $aProt = explode(',', $sProt);
    foreach($aProt as $var){
        $trvar =  trim($var);

        $stmt = $conn ->prepare("SELECT table1.AGICODE, blablabla
                                FROM table1
                                INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.FK_ID = table2.ID 
                                having AGICODE =?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['AGI1']);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Thanks in advance I appreciate your time and help!

edit: typo fixed

Comment: TYPOO: Missing `>` in the `<p><input name="AGI1" type="text" </p>`

Comment: Also you should be checking that `$_POST['AGI1']` Exists before attempting to use its value. Existance is not guaranteed. `if(isset($_POST['AGI1']) && $_POST['AGI1']<>''){`

Comment: ___However when I add more codes___ Can you show an example of `$_POST['AGI1']` when you have used More than one code please

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx/

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you for ur reply. The values I'm testing for AGI exist. Even sometimes if I use on AGI code but type in empty space before it, it also doesn't show output. So i think there's something wrong with the code. What do you mean by "example of `$_POST['AGI1']` "?

Comment: You say it works if you use for example `aaa` but when you ___add more codes___ it does not so does that mean you do `aaa bbb ccc` or `aaa,bbb,ccc,` ??

Comment: I mean `aaa,bbb,ccc` then it doesnt show output. But also i noticed that if i type in empty space and then ` aaa` it also doesn't work.

Comment: Had an error in my answer, which I have now fixed, try again

Answer (score 0):

I would change the query to use `IN()` and not `having` as that normally goes with a `GROUP BY` aggregations. Then make use of all the parameters passed from the user, which could be one or many in the bind process.

```
// while testing for errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

if(isset($_POST['AGI1']) && $_POST['AGI1'] <> ''){
    
    $in_values = explode(',', strtoupper($_POST['AGI1']));
    $in  = str_repeat('?,', count($in_values) - 1) . '?';
    
    $sql = "SELECT table1.AGICODE, blablabla
            FROM table1
                INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.FK_ID = table2.ID 
            WHERE table1.AGICODE IN($in)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $types = str_repeat('s', count($in_values)); //types
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$in_values); 

    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This also isn't working. It gave me an error " Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean " on the line having `$stmt->bind_param("s", $val);`. Also for some reason the new sql code doesn't work in mysql while the other ones does (with HAVING).

Comment: That means the query failed to prepare. I added some debug code, add that and show me the other errors

Comment: This is the error I now get "Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column 'AGICODE' in where clause is ambiguous" on the `$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);` line. What do you think this means? I checked for typos there's none.

Comment: Code amended, just need to add the table name, so `WHERE table1.AGICODE IN($in)";`

Comment: It's now giving me two new errors: " mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement " on the `$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);` and "Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement" on `    $stmt->execute();`. I appreciate your time to help me man, cheers!

Comment: And what was the Input you sent from the browser

Comment: @Dharman Oops, getting my PDO and MYSQLI mixed up, nice spot, fixed it